# Two different beaviour for .tolist() IndexError

Tags: python, pandas, list

I looping over on dataframe `df1`  to look for `maximum order` and then I want to take `discount_first` to assign to max order.

For one dataset everything goes OK

```
new_rate_1 = []
for value in df1["maximum_order"]:
    new_val = df[df["New_Order_Lines"]==value]["discount_first"]
    new_val = new_val.tolist()[0]
    new_rate_1.append(new_val)
new_rate_1 

[-1.3,
 -1.3,
 0.35,
 0.8,
 0.75,
 0.55,
 0.8,
 0.85,
 0.4,
 0.75,
 0.85,
 0.85,
 0.55,
 0.45,
 0.8,
 0.65,
 0.55,
 0.85,
 0.35,
 0.85,
 0.9,
 0.5,
 0.55,
 -0.6,
 0.85,
 0.75,
 0.35,
 0.15,
 0.55,
 0.7,
 0.8,
 0.85,
 0.75,
 0.65,
 0.75,
 0.75,
 0.35,
 0.85,
 0.4,
 ...
 ....
]
```

for other data set i start getting error ?

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I dont index the list within the look I dont get error and output looks like this

```
 [[0.8],
 [0.8],
 [0.55],
 [0.55],
 [0.55],
 [0.85],
 [0.55],
 [0.85],
 [0.85],
 [0.65],
 [0.65],
 [0.75],
 [0.7]
 .....
```

- any suggestion/advice how can I get rid of behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The data list that causes the error evidently contains a empty row somewhere. Double check your data.

Answer (score 0):

How about using this

```
# new_val = new_val.tolist()[0]
new_val = new_val.values.flatten()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why looping at all when you can do it without a loop?

you can use `isin()`+`tolist()` method:

```
new_rate_1 =df.loc[df["New_Order_Lines"].isin(df1["maximum_order"]),"discount_first"].tolist()
```

Comment: I need to loop through because I am going to assign these dicounts to df2 which contanins 77452 entries. basically look for each entry and assign rate. they are duplicated as well

Comment: @user3459293 in both df's do u have any column common(I mean on what basis you are going to assign these values bcz you don't need loop at all)?